# Hölder continuity of uniform limit of piecewise constant functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Consider a piecewise constant function $v: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by a finite partition $a=t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_s=b$ of the interval $[a,b]$, and constants $m_1,m_2,...,m_s$ with $v(t)=m_i$ whenever $t \in I_i := [t_{i-1},t_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,s$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the collection of intervals $I_i$ that make up the partition of [a,b].

Now, let $u: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a regulated function (that is, $u$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of piecewise constant functions $u_n: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) each $u_n$ of which is defined via a corresponding partition $\mathcal{P}_n$ of $[a,b]$ as described above.

Does anyone know of a condition that characterizes when such a function $u$
is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for some $0<\alpha<1$?

E(up)lio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a characterization which is not too close to a tautology; a sufficient condition is the following. Denote the modulus of the subdivision $\mathcal{P}$ by  $\|\mathcal{P}\|:=\max _ {1\le i\le s} (t _ i-t _ {i-1})$, and by $\mathcal{P}^M$ the set of mid-points of the intervals $I\in \mathcal{P}$.

Assume that

**1.** $\|\mathcal{P _ n}\|\to0\, ;$

**2.** ${u _ n} _{|\mathcal{P _ n} }$ are uniformly $\alpha$-Hölder, that is there is $k\ge0$ such that $|u_n(t) - u _ n(s)|\le k|t-s|^\alpha$ holds for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for any $t,s\in\mathcal{P} _ n^M\,  .$

Reason: if $\tilde u _ n$ denotes the piece-wise interpolation of the nodes $\mathcal{P} _ n^M$, then by concavity $\tilde u _ n$ has modulus of continuity $k|t|^\alpha$ on $[a,b]$, and $\| u _ n - \tilde u _ n\| _ \infty\le k\|\mathcal{P} _ n\|^\alpha=o(1)$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore  $u$ has the same modulus of continuity $k|t|^\alpha$.

Comment: First, notice that I edited the question slightly so that the left endpoints are included. Thus, ,instead of $\mathcal{P}_n^0$, let us denote $\mathcal{P}_n^E$ to denote the endpoints (not the midpoints)
of the partition intervals.

Comment: I wonder if changing 2. in the answer above to a similar statement denoted by 2.1 (and stated below) would be enough (under possibly some other conditions on $u$, but only if they are necessary) to allow us to conclude the same result.

2.1 There exists a $k\geq0$ and an $0<\alpha<1$ such that $\abs{u(t)-u(s)} \leq k\abs{t-s}^{\alpha}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for any t,s \in $\mathcal{P}_n^E$.

That is, can we replace 2. with a similar statement as 2. but stated in terms of the limit function $u$ instead of for the sequence $u_n$ (that tends to $u$ in the uniform limit).

Comment: Isn't this the same that saying that the restriction of $u$ to the dense set $D:=\cup_n\mathcal{P}_n^E$ is Hoelder? Then, if $u$ is also continuous, it is certainly Hoelder. So this would somehow make less relevant the role of the sequence $u_n$, that should only satisfy a suitable condition that ensures the continuity of $u$. 

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Again, I really appreciate having someone with whom to discuss this problem with. In my situation, I do in fact know that $u$ is continuous, so this is a very helpful remark. Do you happen to know of any good books in which I can read about all of the different properties of Holder continuity, like some of the properties that you have stated here?

Comment: Suppose that we know that $u$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Moreover, suppose that for every $x \in [a,b)$, we know that there exists a corresponding sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ approaching $x$ from the right side such that:
There exists a $C>0$ and an $0< \alpha <1$, both independent of $x$, such that $\abs{u(x)-u(x_n)} \leq C \abs{x-x_n}^{\alpha}$. I will work to show that $u$ is $C$-uniformly $\alpha$-Holder continuous on $I$. That is, there exists a $C>0$ and $0<\alpha<1$ such that $\abs{u(x)-u(y)} \leq C \abs{x-y}^{\alpha}$ for all $x,y \in I$.

Comment: I don't think the latter is true. Consider the function  on $I:=[-1,+1]$ defined by $u(x)=\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1+\log x|}$ for $x\neq0$ and $u(0)=0$. It is locally Lipscitz in $I\setminus(0)$ so the condition is satisfied for all $x\neq0$, for any $C$ and  $\alpha$. In $x=0$ the condition is also satisfied by a sequence of zeros $x_n\to0$, again for all $C$ and $\alpha$. But $u$ satisfies no Hoelder condition, for no  $C$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: I realized a little bit after posting that comment that the statement was likely not to be true. Thanks for the example: I will examine it carefully.
